# Working a new condition into a header if statement - if URI is a certain page, don't display code that displays everywhere else on the site

Tags: php, javascript, html, if-statement

In the header of my company's website we've got this code calls the javascript that displays our live chat feature. I need it to not display on **just one page**, but I can't really dismantle the current system - the page I'm building absolutely needs to include the universal header, so I figured I'd try and make the header make an exception for my page instead. Here's the code that displays the chat feature:

```
<?php if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])): ?>
<script type="text/javascript" id="*******" src="//www.ourdomain.com/support/scripts/track.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.ourdomain.com/support/scripts/pix.gif" onload="LiveChatFeature.createButton('11111111', this);" style="display:none" />

<?php else: ?>
<script type="text/javascript" id="*******" src="https://www.ourdomain.com/support/scripts/track.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.ourdomain.com/support/scripts/pix.gif" onload="LiveChatFeature.createButton('11111111', this);" style="display:none" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

So I've written the following code, where my-page is the page I need the chat feature to not display:

```
<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'my-page')): ?>
```

But I'm really not sure where to go from here in terms of introducing this in to the existing header if statement and having it not display the chat code. Can any wise and experienced folks out there get me a bit of a direction? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by header architecture?  You're not dealing with headers and you're only reading information anyway so you don't need to worry about things like screwing up the response.

Comment: Perhaps I used confusing language. When I said "header architecture" I simply meant "the header of our website" (i.e. "header.phtml"), which includes the code that places the live chat feature on every page. We're using Magento, so the header of every page is from the same file. I'm a noobish coder, so I'm requesting help integrating a new if statement into the existing code that excludes the chat code if it's on my own page (http://www.ourdomain.com/my-page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit rusty on PHP, but what I understand you want is that for both if statements to return true and then, and only then, it should include your chat code correct?

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'my-page')) : ?>
```

The code above, could return FALSE, if the string is not found, but would return a numeric value (index of the string) if it is found, so you would get weird results. To be 100% sure it was not found, you want to check for:

```
 <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'my-page')===FALSE) : ?>
```

So the two conditions combined would look like this:

```
 <?php if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'my-page')===FALSE) ): ?>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try and get back to you. :)

Comment: I had to remove the second else (it wasn't doing anything anyway) but your two combined conditions worked and that was just the help I was looking for. Thanks!!